# Vue CLI plugin passing dynamic JS variables into props

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using version 4.5 of the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) plugin and have built a component that accepts a `title` as a prop. I've then built my component into a web component and have included it into my HTML web page *(that isn't a Vue JS project)*

I'm trying to now update the props of my component in my HTML & JS project dynamically, and initially thought I could use a JS data attribute and update the data attribute prop as this would work, along with a watcher in my component, but this didn't update with the new dynamic value.

I've read a little online, and have implemented a suggestion, but can't seem to get my component to update with the JS variable, what am I doing wrong or what's the workaround?

```html
<script>
  var creditModalPluginTitle = 'Foo Bar'
</script>

<div style="margin-bottom:10em;">
  <vue-les-creditreport :title="creditModalPluginTitle"></vue-les-creditreport>
</div>
```

Inside of my Credit Report plugin I'm outputting `title` but it's not updating with the value from `creditModalPluginTitle`.

I can't be the only person with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The markup shown looks like it's intended for the non Vue page, where you included your Vue component (`vue-les-creditreport`). This markup uses Vue syntax for data binding (i.e., the `v-bind` directive in `:title="creditModalPluginTitle"`), but that only works *within Vue templates*.

You would need to set the component's `title` property using vanilla JavaScript:

```html
<div style="margin-bottom:10em;">
  <vue-les-creditreport id="myElem"></vue-les-creditreport>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('myElem').title = creditModalPluginTitle
</script>
```